# RadioButtons Internet Explorer double click

Tags: angular, internet-explorer, radio-button

I need help.

I have an Angular2+ project that uses radio buttons (I'm using bootstrap 3) I make an algorithm to make the behaviour like a checkbox with [ngmodel] .... eveything works fine EXCEPT FOR INTERNET EXPLORER I don't know why but in IE I need to double click the radio button to works like the other browsers. What happens ? works in every browser except IE what can I do ? is there any code configuration to avoid this forced double click to work? or what Can I do ? Thanks everyone. Greetings

**HTML**
[image]

**Initialization**
[image]

**The Click Event**
[image]

Comment: Can you share your code? really it's going to be hard to debug this without the dev tools

Comment: Yes, sure. Give a minute

Comment: @Goku There it is

Comment: pull up the developer tools in IE. then navigate to "Sources" then put a breakpoint in the first if statement in onSprint6. click the radio button and tell me what happens. Also, let me know if there are any errors in your console when you do this. Also, please post the entire component that the click event exists in